# What assumptions are made by UL when they equate 30Vrms to 60Vdc for LVLE circuits?

Tags: dc, safety, low-voltage, rms, ul

UL defines Low Voltage Low Energy circuits as "A circuit involving an alternating current
voltage of not more than 30 volts, rms (42.4 volts peak) or a direct current voltage of not more than 60 volts..."  Where does this come from?

If they're talking about power equivalency, then it would be 60Vrms = 60Vdc. If they're talking about peak current equivalencies (thinking about human skin conductivity/resistance?) then I would expect it to be 85 Vpk (\$60 Vdc \cdot \sqrt{2}\$, assuming sinusoidal waveforms). But, it is neither; so, what conditions or assumptions are being made by UL or IEC for this equivalency between 30 Vrms and 60 VDC?

Comment: I have no idea if this is true or not, (and hopefully someone can confirm or give the real reason) but at one point I heard that the limits were set with some margin from the lowest known fatal shock that happened with each type of source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is it comes from the voltage required to trigger the  "clench" response, where it becomes hard to release a grabbed live wire.

Because of the way nerves work, DC currents tend to cause an initial reaction but this fades due to polarization.  With AC, the reversing polarity "resets" nerves and causes continued contraction.

I definitely know from personal experience, that even fairly low AC voltages are *much* more painful than DC....

Comment: so, it's not so much a mathematical equivalence, but a physiological-response one?

Comment: That is my understanding and experience.